# Download files when exact URL is not known

Tags: r, download

From [this link](http://cdn.servel.cl/padronesauditados/padron.html), I´m trying to download multiple pdf files, but I can´t get the exact URL for each file.

To access one of the pdf files, you could click on "Región de Arica y Parinacota" and then click on "Arica". Then, you can check that the url is http://cdn.servel.cl/padronesauditados/padron/A1501001.pdf, if you click on the next link "Camarones" you now noticed that the URL is http://cdn.servel.cl/padronesauditados/padron/A1501002.pdf

I checked more URLs, and they all have a similar pattern:

"A" + "two digit number from 1 to 15" + "two digit number of unknown range" + "three digit number of unknown range"

Even though the URL examples I showed seem to suggest that the file names are named sequentally, this is not always the case.

What I did to be able to download all the files despite not knowing the exact URLs I did the following:

1) I made a for loop in order to write all possible file names based on the pattern I describe above, i.e, A0101001.pdf, A0101002.pdf....A1599999.pdf

```
library(downloader)
library(stringr)
reg.ind <- 1:15
pro.ind <- 1:99
com.ind <- 1:999
reg <- str_pad(reg.ind, width=2, side="left", pad="0")
prov <- str_pad(pro.ind, width=2, side="left", pad="0")
com  <- str_pad(com.ind, width=3, side="left", pad="0")

file <- c()
for(i in 1:length(reg)){
 reg.i <- reg[i]
    for(j in 1:length(prov)){
        prov.j <- prov[j]
            for(k in 1:length(com)){
                com.k <- com[k]
                file <- c(file, (paste0("A", reg.i, prov.j, com.k)))
            }
        }
    }
```

2) then I used another for loop to download a file everytime I hit a correct URL. I use `tryCatch`to ignore the cases when the URL was incorrect (most of the time)

```
for(i in 1:length(file)){
 tryCatch({
 url <- paste0("http://cdn.servel.cl/padronesauditados/padron/", file[i], 
 ".pdf")
# change destfile accordingly if you decide to run the code
download.file(url, destfile = paste0("./datos/comunas/",  file[i], ".pdf"), 
mode = "wb")
}, error = function(e){})
}
```

PROBLEM: In total I know there are not more than 400 pdf files, as each one of them correspond to a commune in Chile, but I wrote a vector with 1483515 possible file names, and therefore my code, even though it works, takes a much longer time than if I could manage to obtain the file names before hand.

Does anyone know how to workaround this problem?

Comment: What about command window and wget?   `wget -r -l1 --no-parent -A.pdf http://cdn.servel.cl/padronesauditados/padron/`

Comment: And final comment: usually these digits are referring to something. (I know sometimes they are just random but here they seem to have a meaning). If you can decipher that, then you can code it efficiently.

Comment: @Masoud ; are you sure this is a dupe - seems that website needs to have things clicked - maybe javascript - rather than just looking for xml nodes

Comment: @user20650 nah, maybe I took it way too simple.

Comment: Hi Masoud, I didn´t know about `wget` I´ll check it. I suppose my problem is a little bit different from the question you linked, as in that post, it is possible to webscrape the file names. When I check the source code of the link I shared, the file names I´m looking for are not there.
Indeed, some of the digits make sense, but there are others that doesn´t seem to follow any logic, therefore I just tried to cover every possible solution...though I started the script about 4 hours ago and it is still running :p

Comment: @csmontt wget won't work. I gave it a try. There are 347 files. But the links are getting produced on click(or whatever the the technical term is. Look at this line: `<p><a href="#" download onclick="javascript:setDocumento(this, 999); return false;" name="PadronElectoralExtranjeros.pdf">Padrón Electoral `). I dunno enough javascript to help you with that but I would suggest using [tag:js].

Comment: @Masoud thanks for sparing me time of trying that myself. Don´t have enough time to learn javascript right now though, I´ll just wait for my script to finish. Thanks again.

Comment: It looks like the information you are looking for is store in an XML file: http://cdn.servel.cl/padronesauditados/archivos.xml

Comment: That´s exactly what I need!! thanks! may I ask you how did you get there?

Comment: Using the developer tools on your browser, look at the network tab and reload the web page.  Most (not all) of these web pages which use Java script will have the data store in a XHR type of file.

Comment: @Dave2e I didn´t have a clue, very useful thanks!

Comment: Man, alcanzaste a bajar el PDF de los Inhabilitados para sufragar?

Comment: no, no los bajé

Answer (score 1):

You can re-create the "browser developer tools" experience in R with [`splashr`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/splashr):

```
library(splashr) # devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/splashr")
library(tidyverse)

sp <- start_splash()

Sys.sleep(3) # give the docker container time to work

res <- render_har(url = "http://cdn.servel.cl/padronesauditados/padron.html", 
                  response_body=TRUE)

map_chr(har_entries(res), c("request", "url"))
##  [1] "http://cdn.servel.cl/padronesauditados/padron.html"
##  [2] "http://cdn.servel.cl/padronesauditados/stylesheets/navbar-cleaned.min.css"
##  [3] "http://cdn.servel.cl/padronesauditados/stylesheets/virtue.min.css"
##  [4] "http://cdn.servel.cl/padronesauditados/stylesheets/virtue2.min.css"
##  [5] "http://cdn.servel.cl/padronesauditados/stylesheets/custom.min.css"
##  [6] "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato%3A400%2C700%7CRoboto%3A100%2C300%2C400%2C500%2C700%2C900%2C100italic%2C300italic%2C400italic%2C500italic%2C700italic%2C900italic&ver=1458748651"
##  [7] "http://cdn.servel.cl/padronesauditados/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.css"
##  [8] "http://cdn.servel.cl/padronesauditados/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/external/jquery/jquery.js"
##  [9] "http://cdn.servel.cl/padronesauditados/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.js"
## [10] "http://cdn.servel.cl/padronesauditados/images/logo-txt-retina.png"
## [11] "http://cdn.servel.cl/assets/img/nav_arrows.png"
## [12] "http://cdn.servel.cl/padronesauditados/images/loader.gif"
## [13] "http://cdn.servel.cl/padronesauditados/archivos.xml"
## [14] "http://cdn.servel.cl/padronesauditados/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png"
## [15] "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/zN7GBFwfMP4uA6AR0HCoLQ.ttf"
## [16] "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/RxZJdnzeo3R5zSexge8UUaCWcynf_cDxXwCLxiixG1c.ttf"
## [17] "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/Hgo13k-tfSpn0qi1SFdUfaCWcynf_cDxXwCLxiixG1c.ttf"
## [18] "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/Jzo62I39jc0gQRrbndN6nfesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.ttf"
## [19] "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/d-6IYplOFocCacKzxwXSOKCWcynf_cDxXwCLxiixG1c.ttf"
## [20] "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/mnpfi9pxYH-Go5UiibESIqCWcynf_cDxXwCLxiixG1c.ttf"
## [21] "http://cdn.servel.cl/padronesauditados/stylesheets/fonts/virtue_icons.woff"
## [22] "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v13/v0SdcGFAl2aezM9Vq_aFTQ.ttf"
## [23] "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v13/DvlFBScY1r-FMtZSYIYoYw.ttf"
```

Spotting the XML entry is easy in ^^, so we can focus on it:

```
har_entries(res)[[13]]$response$content$text %>% 
  openssl::base64_decode() %>% 
  xml2::read_xml() %>% 
  xml2::xml_find_all(".//Region") %>% 
  map_df(~{
    data_frame(
      id = xml2::xml_find_all(.x, ".//id") %>% xml2::xml_text(),
      nombre = xml2::xml_find_all(.x, ".//nombre") %>% xml2::xml_text(),
      nomcomuna = xml2::xml_find_all(.x, ".//comunas/comuna/nomcomuna") %>% xml2::xml_text(),
      id_archivo = xml2::xml_find_all(.x, ".//comunas/comuna/idArchivo") %>% xml2::xml_text(),
      archcomuna = xml2::xml_find_all(.x, ".//comunas/comuna/archcomuna") %>% xml2::xml_text()
    )
  })
## # A tibble: 346 x 5
##       id                       nombre     nomcomuna id_archivo   archcomuna
##    <chr>                        <chr>         <chr>      <chr>        <chr>
##  1     1 Región de Arica y Parinacota         Arica          1 A1501001.pdf
##  2     1 Región de Arica y Parinacota     Camarones          2 A1501002.pdf
##  3     1 Región de Arica y Parinacota General Lagos          3 A1502002.pdf
##  4     1 Región de Arica y Parinacota         Putre          4 A1502001.pdf
##  5     2           Región de Tarapacá Alto Hospicio          5 A0103002.pdf
##  6     2           Región de Tarapacá        Camiña          6 A0152002.pdf
##  7     2           Región de Tarapacá      Colchane          7 A0152003.pdf
##  8     2           Región de Tarapacá         Huara          8 A0152001.pdf
##  9     2           Región de Tarapacá       Iquique          9 A0103001.pdf
## 10     2           Región de Tarapacá          Pica         10 A0152004.pdf
## # ... with 336 more rows

stop_splash(sp) # don't forget to clean up!
```

You can then either programmatically download all the PDFs by using the URL prefix: `http://cdn.servel.cl/padronesauditados/padron/`

Comment: Thanks @hrbmstr, that looks very handy! though when trying to run the code I get the following error after executing `sp <- start_splash()`        
`Error: Failed to execute '' (The parameter is incorrect)`